# Is it possible to FORCE the Jasper report header, detail and the footer of a group to appear on the same page

Tags: java, jasper-reports, footer

Suppose I have the following group, with a header, a detail and a content.

```
Group 1 HEADER  
Group 1 DETAIL 1  
Group 1 DETAIL 2  
...  
Group 1 DETAIL n  
Group 1 FOOTER
```

I want that HEADER, DETAIL and FOOTER are always be rendered together, on **the same page**, as they would be included in unique "*unbreakable bloc*"

An example of what **I don't want** (the page break between Group 1 DETAIL n  and FOOTER)

```
Group 1 HEADER  
Group 1 DETAIL 1  
Group 1 DETAIL 2  
...  
Group 1 DETAIL n  
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-PAGE BREAK
Group 1 FOOTER
```

In this situation, I want the HEADER, DETAIL and FOOTER block to be moved entirely to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the header and footer is always on each page. You can always set your report height to an extremely large number if this report is meant to be exported to xls for example.